# How can I override JQuery's .show() and .hide() to trigger events before and after?

Tags: jquery, callback, overriding

I am tryign to override the JQuery's .show and .hide methods to launch trigger events before and after they are called with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataBox').bind('afterShow', function () {
        alert('afterShow');
    });
    $('#dataBox').bind('afterHide', function () {
        alert('afterHide');
    });
    $('#dataBox').bind('beforeShow', function () {
        alert('beforeShow');
    });
    $('#dataBox').bind('beforeHide', function () {
        alert('beforeHide');
    });
    $('#toggleButton').click(function(){
        if($('#dataBox').is(':visible')) {
            $('#dataBox').hide ();
        } else {
            $('#dataBox').show();
        }
    });
});

jQuery(function ($) {
    var _oldShow = $.fn.show;
    //Override jquery's 'show()' method to include two triggered events before and after
    $.fn.show = function (speed, oldCallback) {
        return $(this).each(function () {
            var obj = $(this),
                newCallback = function () {
                    if ($.isFunction(oldCallback)) {
                        oldCallback.apply(obj);
                }
                obj.trigger('afterShow');
            };
        obj.trigger('beforeShow');
            _oldShow.apply(obj, [speed, newCallback]);
        });
    }
});

jQuery(function ($) {
    var _oldHide = $.fn.hide;
    //Override jquery's 'hide()' method to include two triggered events before and after
    $.fn.hide = function (speed, oldCallback) {
        return $(this).each(function () {
            var obj = $(this),
                newCallback = function () {
                    if ($.isFunction(oldCallback)) {
                        oldCallback.apply(obj);
                }
                obj.trigger('afterHide');
            };
        obj.trigger('beforeHide');
            _oldHide.apply(obj, [speed, newCallback]);
        });
    }
});
```

I have the following Markup:

```
<input type='text' id='dataBox'/>
<input type='button' value='toggle' id='toggleButton' />
```

When I click the toggle button the 'beforeHide' and 'beforeShow' events are triggering while the 'afterShow' and 'afterHide' aren't. Can anyone clue me in as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

plz check the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahen/eUaAw/5/) . hope it works

**$.show / $.hide - override function:**

```
(function($){
$.override ={'show': $.fn.show, 'hide': $.fn.hide};

$.each($.override,function(M,F){

        var m=M.replace( /^\w/, function(r){ return r.toUpperCase(); });

        $.fn[M] = function(speed, easing, callback) {

            var args=[speed||0,easing||'',callback||function(){}];

            if( $.isFunction(speed)){
                args[2]=speed;
                args[0]=0;
            }                   
            else if( $.isFunction(easing)){
                args[2]=easing;
                args[1]='';
            }                   

            if(!this.selector){
                F.apply(this, arguments);
                return this;
            }

            return this.each(function () {
                var obj = $(this),
                    oldCallback = args[args.length-1],
                    newCallback = function () {
                        if ($.isFunction(oldCallback)){
                            oldCallback.apply(obj);
                        }
                        obj.trigger('after'+m);
                };

                obj.trigger('before'+m);
                args[args.length-1]=newCallback;

                //alert(args);
                F.apply(obj,args);

            });
        }
});
})(jQuery);
```

**usage**

```
jQuery(function($){
var $dataBox=$('#dataBox').bind('beforeHide afterHide beforeShow afterShow', function(e) {
    alert(e.type);
});

$('#toggleButton').bind('click',function(){
    $dataBox[$dataBox.is(':visible')?'hide':'show'](100,'swing',function(){ alert('end of animation');});
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Btw, do you have any idea why we have to pass defaults to jQuery's original show function like `duration||0` why cant we call that without duration as `0` with just only newCallBack?

Comment: @Joy if ( speed || speed === 0 ) { // you can animate with callback  }
if first argument is callback, then it takes 
speed = jQuery.fx.speeds._default = 400 (ms);

Comment: hmm, I discovered that several days ago, that we cant call it like `$.show(undefined,callback)` or `$.show(undefined,undefined,callback)` in which case callback will never be called. Maybe it's because of the Argument normalization jQuery does.I learned several good things on jQuery while exploring this problem.

Comment: @Joy! ya. callback must be last argument. so  if speed is not passed, jQuery'll set it 400ms.

Comment: This is elegant and efficient, exactly what I was looking for, thanks loads rahen, also thanks to Joy for his contributions.

Comment: @WilliamCalleja! You are most welcome. glad to know that it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I set some breakpoints in your code and saw that you `newCallback` function is never being called. Thats I think because you are not using the speed param when you are calling that function.
As you can see from jQuery's original function's doc [$.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/), you can call `$.show` with `no`, `one`, `two` or `three parameters

> .show( duration [, callback] )
>
> durationA string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> callbackA function to call once the animation is complete.
>
> version added: 1.4.3
>
> .show( [duration] [,easing] [, callback] )
>
> durationA string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> easingA string indicating which easing function to use for the transition.
>
> callbackA function to call once the animation is complete.

So you you may or may not pass a bunch of different parameters. So I think the problem is in this line

```
 _oldHide.apply(obj, [speed, newCallback]);
```

Where in this specific case `speed` is undefined.

And you can call `$.fn.show` function like

```
$(..).show(undefined,callBack)
//or
$(..).show(undefined,undefined, callBack)
```

The callback will always have to be the first argument if no other argument is specified and in that case jQuery will use it's default `400ms` speed/duration for the animation. And you will see a fadeIn/fadeOut type of effect. To make it behave like show/hide with this callback

You have to call `_oldShow/_oldHide` like

```
_oldShow.apply(obj, [0,newCallback]);

//or

_oldHide.apply(obj, [0,newCallback]);
```

In a quick Search I found a a code in the internet which seems to work fine and have special handling for all arguments you can pass to `$.show` and `$.hide` . Check the following fiddle to have a look at that

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/T3TN2/2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I had seen this solution but my gripe with it was that even though a speed was not being sent to the 'show()' method it was still doing the animation. Why is that?

Comment: The Fiddle link, it always seems to perform a slow show/hide animation even if it not being called. I'm viewing it on firefox

Comment: I didn't know that, but before I had the custom code everytime I called 'show' and 'hide' there was no 400ms animation going on, it jsut switched them on and off normally.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not for 'fade' that you're referring to?

Comment: Opps! Sorry I was thinking of `fade` maybe, my bad. without a `speed` param `show` is like `display:block` and `hide` is like `display:none`

Comment: Ok, I mean that's the idea, but the fiddle solution is doing some sort of fade. which is wrong and additionally it seems to be messing with the show/hide functions. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Hmm it seems to be doing so which it shouldn't, but you can force `show/hide` like behavior by passing a speed value of `0`. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/drv5w/30/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm attempting to override the 'show/hide' functions in order to avoid having to go through the entire code and make the alterations and then having to remember the reason why now 'our show/hide' methods require a '0' in their parameters, not to mention writing a standard for the rest of the people in the office to use.

Comment: Latest fiddle, I forgot to update after modification last time http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/T3TN2/2 . Btw, Rahen's Code structure is much better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

### Why the `afterShow` and `afterHide` events are not being triggered

jQuery will only call the callback function (`newCallback` in your code) if the show / hide is animated. If no parameters are passed to `.show()` / `.hide()` (or if `speed` is `undefined`), then jQuery will show / hide the element(s) directly, and the callback function will not be executed.

### Why overriding `.show()` / `.hide()` isn't the best idea

- jQuery calls `.show()` / `.hide()` internally (e.g. as part of `.fadeTo()`) and recursively (when doing an animated show / hide), so your custom events will be triggered when you may not be expecting them to.
- IMHO it's best to keep "stock" jQuery and customizations separate (as plugins), with separate method names / namespaces:

  - When your developers look up stock methods in http://api.jquery.com, they'll know that the documentation describes the methods' behaviour completely.
  - If your developers work on code from elsewhere, they won't call stock methods and expect behaviour that's specific to your company's codebase.

### `.eventedShow()` / `.eventedHide()`

This adds `.eventedShow()` and `.eventedHide()` (which takes the same arguments as `.show()` / `.hide()`) and should do what you want:

```
(function( $ ) {

$.each( [ 'Show', 'Hide' ], function( i, method ) {
    $.fn[ 'evented' + method ] = function( speed ) {
        var originalMethod = method.toLowerCase(),
            hasCallback = false,
            args;

        // animate
        if ( speed || speed === 0 ) {
            args = $.makeArray( arguments );
            $.each( args, function( i, arg ) {
                if ( $.isFunction( arg ) ) {
                    args[ i ] = function() {
                        arg.apply( this, arguments );
                        $( this ).trigger( 'after' + method );
                    };
                    hasCallback = true;
                    return false;
                }
            } );
            if ( !hasCallback ) {
                args.push( function() {
                    $( this ).trigger( 'after' + method );
                } );
            }

            this.each( function() {
                var el = $( this );
                el.queue( function() {
                    $( this )
                        .trigger( 'before' + method )
                        .dequeue();
                } );
                $.fn[ originalMethod ].apply( el, args );
            } );

        // straight show/hide
        } else {
            this.trigger( 'before' + method );
            $.fn[ originalMethod ].apply( this, arguments );
            this.trigger( 'after' + method );
        }

        return this;
    };
} );

})( jQuery );
```

You can try the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/bv8D2/

You'd still need to change `show` / `hide` to `eventedShow` / `eventedHide` in your existing code, but this can be done with a global search-and-replace.

Comment: Jeffery! great. but problem is if you pass 1st param as callback, animation takes 400ms to complete. and Willam asked to fix that.

Comment: @rahen If you want to have code execute after a straight show/hide, then do it directly, i.e. el.show(); callback(); There's no need to pass it as a callback function.

Comment: ! u'r rite. by the way, I've modified your code to fill up William's requirement. plz check the [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahen/eUaAw/6/).