# How can I prevent an event from finish firing on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capture when someone tries to close "edit mode" on a page and tell them to save changes.

What triggers edit mode is a collapse element, first child is "View", second child is "Edit". I also have an event listener attached to the "hide" event of the edit child, so when they click to collapse the edit mode, they will receive a message asking them if they want to continue without saving. Problem is, I ask them, and if they hit continue, everything is fine, but if they hit cancel, I want the edit mode to STOP collapsing, and remain as it is.

I've tried with e.preventDefault, stopImmediatePropagation, return false, nothing works.

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" id="my-accordion">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-items">
                <li id="firstTab" class="active"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab" class="tab-item">First</a></li>
                <li id="secondTab"><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab" class="tab-item">Second</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group" id="edit" style="display:none;">
        <div class="accordion-heading center">
            <a id="edit-toggler" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#my-accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                <i class='icon-arrow-up'></i> Open Edit <i class='icon-arrow-up'></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#batch-edit').on('hide', function () { // THIS IS FOR THE BATCH EDIT BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('toggle');
    $('#edit-toggler').html("<i class='icon-arrow-up'></i> Open Edit <i class='icon-arrow-up'></i>");
    isEdit = false;
    if(UserEditing){
        if(!confirm('Leave without saving?')) { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    // DO SOME STUFF
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to show both the relevant HTML and your code for us to know how to help.

Comment: I'm afraid, there's no such thing as a *`hide` event*. Also, what is the `collapse` method in your code? Are you using a plugin or extending the jQuery object somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no native hide/show event you can bind to.  This just means we need to trigger these custom events ourselves.

Take a look at [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702202/how-can-i-override-jquerys-show-and-hide-to-trigger-events-before-and-aft)  Here is [the link to the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rahen/eUaAw/5/)

I did something similar to the solution in the answer linked above in order to get `beforeHide`, `afterHide`, `beforeShow` and `afterShow` events.

The snippet below can demo the events mentioned above.

```js
var $show = $('#show'),
$hide = $('#hide'),
$batchEdit = $('#batch-edit');

$show.hide();

$show.on('click', function()
{
$show.hide();
$hide.show();
$batchEdit.show();
});

$hide.on('click', function()
{
$show.show();
$hide.hide();
$batchEdit.hide();
});

$batchEdit.on('beforeHide', function ()
{
alert('triggered beforeHide');
$show.show();
$hide.hide();
})
.on('afterHide', function ()
{
alert('triggered afterHide');
})
.on('beforeShow', function ()
{
alert('triggered beforeShow');
$show.hide();
$hide.show();
})
.on('afterShow', function ()
{
alert('triggered afterShow');
});

(function($){

$.override ={'show': $.fn.show, 'hide': $.fn.hide};

$.each($.override,function(M,F){
    
    var m=M.replace( /^\w/, function(r){ return r.toUpperCase(); });
        
    $.fn[M] = function(speed, easing, callback) {
            
        var args=[speed||0,easing||'',callback||function(){}];
            
        if( $.isFunction(speed)){
            args[2]=speed;
            args[0]=0;
        }                      
        if( $.isFunction(easing)){
            args[2]=easing;
            args[1]='';
        }                    

        if(!this.selector){
            F.apply(this, arguments);
            return this;
        }
                
        return this.each(function () {
            var obj = $(this),
                oldCallback = args[args.length-1],
                newCallback = function () {
                    if ($.isFunction(oldCallback)){
                        oldCallback.apply(obj);
                    }
                    obj.trigger('after'+m);
                };
                
            obj.trigger('before'+m);
            args[args.length-1]=newCallback;
                
            //alert(args);
            F.apply(obj,args);

        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="batch-edit">Batch Edit</div>
<input type='button' id="show" value='Show'>
<input type='button' id="hide" value = 'Hide'>
```